# Display records from sql database order by date newest first PHP

Tags: php, web

Thanks for looking. I'm trying to have posts on my website appear on the homepage as newest at the top.

As the posts are uploaded they go to the back of the list e.g. A new post would go to page 3 rather than the top of the homepage.

The code I have so far is:

```
$query = "SELECT u.username,p.* FROM posts  as p, users as u where p.user_id=u.user_id LIMIT $page_1, $per_page";
```

What would be necessary in order to have the newest posts shown at the top of the list rather than the end?

If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask

The code is written in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I got it working...

In-case anyone else needs this, the code used to display newest post was..

```
                $query = "SELECT u.username,p.* FROM posts  as p, users as u where p.user_id=u.user_id ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT $page_1, $per_page ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ORDER BY 
if you have post creation date column you can use:

```
$query = "SELECT u.username,p.* FROM posts  as p, users as u where p.user_id=u.user_id ORDER BY date_column DESC LIMIT $page_1, $per_page";
```

if you don't have creation date column you can use:

```
$query = "SELECT u.username,p.* FROM posts  as p, users as u where p.user_id=u.user_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $page_1, $per_page";
```